# Computation of address of an matrix element is not convincing

Tags: matrix

When I want to calculate the address of a matrix element (static memory), we have two approaches:

1. Row Major System:

The address of a location in Row Major System is calculated using the following formula:

```
Address of A [ I ][ J ] = B + W * [ N * ( I – Lr ) + ( J – Lc ) ]
```

2. Column Major System:

The address of a location in Column Major System is calculated using the following formula:

```
Address of A [ I ][ J ] Column Major Wise = B + W * [( I – Lr ) + M * ( J – Lc )]
```

where

> B = Base address
>
> I = Row subscript of element whose address is to be found
>
> J = Column subscript of element whose address is to be found
>
> W = Storage Size of one element stored in the array (in byte)
>
> Lr = Lower limit of row/start row index of matrix, if not given assume
>   0 (zero)
>
> Lc = Lower limit of column/start column index of matrix, if not given
>   assume 0 (zero)
>
> M = Number of row of the given matrix
>
> N = Number of column of the given matrix

When I am calculating the address of the same element with different approach, why should I get different addresses as result of the formula applied? 
The element of the matrix is still in the same location (address).

Answer (score 0):

```
I would like to suggest you , instead of going through the formula, lets understand how the formula got arrived.

The following is for Row Major System. You can similarly use the below logic to find for Column Major System.

Suppose there is the following array of size , array[3][4]

A00 A01 A02 A03
A10 A11 A12 A13
A20 A21 A22 A23
A30 A31 A32 A33

Now you have the Base address i.e. of A00. Suppose you want to calculate the address of A22. Here is the logic that we will apply: 

A22 is in the 3rd row and 3rd column. This means that we need to travel first 2 rows, each containing 4 elements, to reach the 3rd row. But after passing 2nd row  and reaching in the 3rd row, our element is still 3 items away. then we need to add 3 more position to get our desired element i.e. A22.

Mathematically , I can write it:

number of elements in each row = 4
Number of rows to travel = 2
Additional columns addition to reach our element = 3

Therefore , we need to pass (4*2)+3 elements to reach our goal

> In formula, it can be written as baseAddress +
> (columnNumberOfOriginalMatrix*rowNumberOfPositionToBeFind) +
> columnNumberOfPositionToBeFind

i.e for A22 in A[3][4]
columnNumberOfOriginalMatrix = 4
rowNumberOfPositionToBeFind = 2
columnNumberOfPositionToBeFind = 2

A22 = baseAddress + (4*2)+2

But we need to multiply this whole function with a number, depending upon the data type of matrix. IF its int, then we know that each address will be incremented by  4 bytes. 

Therefore Address of A[i][j] = (baseAddress + (columnNumberOfOriginalMatrix*rowNumberOfPositionToBeFind) + columnNumberOfPositionToBeFind) * sizeOfDatatype
```